# crash at (operator new(unsigned int)+22)

Tags: c++, memory-management, opengl-es, android-ndk, new-operator

im trying to find the cause of the following crash reported on android:

**crash at (operator new(unsigned int)+22)**

does it mean that memory was not allocated successfully ? and if so, adding std::nothrow and null check and exit the program is the right solution?

is there a way i can limit the program to not allocate in order to reproduce it ?

the code where it crash :

```
glCompileShader( VSID );

GLint vstat;
glGetShaderiv( VSID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vstat );

if( vstat != GL_TRUE )
{
    GLint infolen;
    glGetShaderiv( VSID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infolen );

    GLchar* infostring = new GLchar[infolen + 1];

    glGetShaderInfoLog( VSID, infolen, nullptr, infostring );
    infostring[infolen] = 0;

    std::stringstream Error;
    Error << "An Error occured while trying to compile"\
        " Vertex Shader \"" << VertexShaderPath
        << "\":\n\n" << infostring;
}
```

Comment: It's the `new GLchar[infolen + 1];` that crashes, I suppose? What's the value of `infolen` when it crashes?

Comment: It's a good practice to check for errors if some function calls may trigger them, such as OpenGL function calls. If you ignore them, you can then observe strange behavior.

Comment: @DanielLangr can you elaborate more?

Comment: @dvrer See https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error. Also, the documentation for each OpenGL function lists the particular errors that function call may result in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A crash in operator [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) or [`new[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) can be caused by:

- unsuccessful allocation.  For example if `infolen` is too large compared to the available memory.
- a crash in the constructor of the object(s) being allocated. But with `GLchar`, this is not very probable.

You should add code to handle the exception, by enclosing new in a `try`..`catch` block (as demonstrated [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/bad_alloc/)) so to terminate graciously.

If you invoke new with [`nothrow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/nothrow) you should then check the returned pointer for being different than `nullptr` in order to avoid nasty UB.

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems with your code: First you're not checking if `glGetShaderiv` is successful or not; if not, then `infolen` remains uninitialized. Less a problem and only an issue if running in buggy environments is, that you're not using the `length` pointer of `glGetShaderInfoLog` for adding the null terminator at the end; it's always a good practice to retrieve that value as well as consistency check.

Also I suggest you use a `std::string` instead of manual allocation:

```
std::string infostring;
while( GL_NO_ERROR != glGetError() ); /* Flush Errors */

GLenum err;
glCompileShader( VSID );
if( GL_NO_ERROR == (err = glGetError())
){
    GLint vstat = 0;
    glGetShaderiv( VSID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vstat );

    if( (GL_NO_ERROR == (err = glGetError()))
     && vstat != GL_TRUE
    ){
        GLint infolen = 0;
        glGetShaderiv( VSID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infolen );
        if( (GL_NO_ERROR == (err = glGetError()))
         && 0 < infolen
        ){
            GLsizei returned_infolen = 0;
            infostring = std::string(infolen, 0);
            glGetShaderInfoLog( VSID, infolen, &returned_infolen, infostring.data() );
            infostring.resize(returned_infolen);

            err = glGetError();
    }
}
if( GL_NO_ERROR != err
){
       std::stringstream Error;
        Error << "An Error occured while trying to compile"\
            " Vertex Shader \"" << VertexShaderPath
            << "\":\n\n" << infostring;
}
```